# Installing Simple GUI Extension on Bluej

Tags: java, user-interface, bluej

I am planning on creating a simple GUI design for my project (Room Booking System) but one problem... I'm no good with GUI's, I have found an Extension for the program i use (Bluej) the extension being 'Simple GUI Extension' I have downloaded the Extension but having problems on getting the extension on bluej, I have searched videos on how to install but can't find any and also thought they might be a tutorial on how to install the extension on the website i downloaded it from but there isn't so if there is anyone who possibly knows how to install this extension it would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using BlueJ? Why not move to a more industry standard IDE like Eclipse, Netbeans or IntelliJ?

Comment: This is what I have learnt to use in university so not being the best at writing java I find Bluej easy as it separates different methods using colored boxes and I find it easier to understand and not get confused. I plan to move onto using eclipse but at the moment I am comfortable with Bluej.

Comment: That's cool man, learn at your own pace. But try to avoid becoming dependent on it. You want to be able to visualise that on your own, without the need for visual cues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a grand choice of [three places you could put the extension](http://www.bluej.org/extensions/extensions.html):

> **For all users of this system in all projects:**
>
> `<BLUEJ_HOME>/lib/extensions (Unix), or <BLUEJ_HOME>\lib\extensions (Windows), or <BLUEJ_HOME>/BlueJ.app/Contents/Resources/Java/extensions (Mac, Control-click BlueJ.app and choose Show Package Contents`
>
> **For a single user for all projects:**
>
> `<USER_HOME>/.bluej/extensions (Unix), or <USER_HOME>\bluej\extensions (Windows), or <USER_HOME>/Library/Preferences/org.bluej/extensions (Mac)`
>
> **For this project only:**
>
> `<BLUEJ_PROJECT>/extensions`

Of course, `<BLUEJ_HOME>` refers to BlueJ's installation directory, `<USER_HOME>` refers to your user directory, and `<BLUEJ_PROJECT>` refers to your current BlueJ project. Just put it in one of those directories, restart BlueJ and you should be good to go.

Comment: berry120, I've tried all these locations on Linux Mint 17 and Linux Mint Debian Edition, and none seem to work. My BLUEJ_HOME is /usr/share/bluej. I have also copied the file into the BLUEJ_HOME folder. The extension works well on Windows 7, however, I prefer Linux. Got any other suggestions?